# Is it possible to launch XSS if only the left angle bracket is encoded

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript

I find some website only encode the left angle bracket of inserted HTML tag, for example:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:63.35px;top:108.41px" class="cls_002"><span class="cls_002">&lt;script>alert("hello")&lt;/script></span></div>
```

Is it still possible to launch XSS on these websites?

Comment: Are quotes encoded for you to prevent you from escaping an attribute context?

Comment: Also, I would search the page for HTML errors. A lone `<` at the right spot is all you need

Comment: As you can see, the double quote is not encoded. But the script is placed between the <div> and <span> tag, I can't see unencoded double quote can make any difference?

Comment: It does if you can find input that is placed into a tag attribute.

Comment: no, you need the left bracket. I noticed/discovered years back that you can actually have a ton of right angle brackets in html w/o it freaking out, but one left-angle and whoa nelly, stop the press...

Comment: XSS exploits tend to target attributes, not elements. See [XSS cheat sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.html)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this could only be abused in two ways:

1. There is an orphaned left bracket in the HTML present in a location that would get corrected by your browser on render. This way, you can construct a valid starting tag.
2. You are able to inject input within an element's attribute, where you can break out of the quotes and inject other attributes that include XSS, like `onload=alert(1)`.